# How can I dynamically change the linked server in a view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a bunch of views that all use `OPENQUERY` to query a view, similar to what you see below. I need to dynamically change the target linked server based on what the current DB is. The overall reason is because we want to line up every data source for our end users as needed. So if they are using DB1 on the front end, then they need to also be using LinkedServer1, if DB2, then LinkedServer2...etc. How would I accomplish this with a view? If it's not possible with a view, then what other methods are available? Right now we have a lot of reports and stored procedures using these views and they are all hardcoded to use `LinkedServer1`.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test]
AS

    --If DB_Name() = 'DB1', then use LinkedServer1
    --If DB_Name() = 'DB2', then use LinkedServer2
    --If DB_Name() = 'DB3', then use LinkedServer3
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer1, 'SELECT * FROM RemoteTable') AS t

GO
```

Comment: Seems like you want to consider a Table-Valued Function

Comment: It is indeed not possible to do this with a view. If all you need is a `SELECT *` (i.e. a direct passthrough) consider using a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) and a four-part name (`CREATE SYNONYM test FOR LinkedServer1.DB.dbo.RemoteTable`) in each separate database.

Comment: View `dbo.test` must exist in each DB so why can you not create each view with the correct LinkedServer?

Comment: @Stu because every so often we will refresh DB2 and DB3 with DB1

Comment: Then include some process that dynamically alters the view as part of that process.

Comment: @Stu that's our plan Z, yes. But we hesitated on that because a gut feeling tells us that that is too messy and error prone.

Answer (score -1):

Can try to declare DB_Name as variable

```
declare @DBName varchar(3) -- DB1 DB2 DB3
declare @LinkedServer varchar(13)
declare @TSQL varchar(max)

SET @LinkedServer = concat('LinkedServer',right(@DBName,1))

set @TSQL = 
'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test]
AS
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ',SELECT * FROM RemoteTable'') AS t
GO' 

exec @TSQL
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/FYAtKUks